# Processing ImageResizer images with 300dpi resolution

Tags: imageresizer

I have been using ImageResizer for a number of years, saving 300 dpi images which when processed end up with a resolution of 96 dpi when stored in my SQL database.

I now want to maintain the 300 dpi resolution but cannot find any command that does this.

What is the way to achieve this?

I have tried changing the default setting for resizeCropSettings from 90 to 100. This does change the size of the saved image but when I view the image properties it still shows it as a resolution of 96 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

DPI is nothing more than metadata. You can set it with the `&dpi=300` command.